# jQuery AJAX form not sending

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

Why isn't this data being sent to my controller? No sign of jsonForm in firebug. No success alert.

**JS**

```
$('form').submit(function() {

  var title = $('#title:input').val();

  alert(title);

  var urlsStr = $("#links").val();
  var urls = urlsStr.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/[^\s]+/gi);
  var formData = {
    "title": title,
    "urls": urls
  }
  var jsonForm = JSON.stringify(formData);                

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: { jsonForm: jsonForm },
    url: 'publishlinks/publish',
    success:
      function(response) {
        alert('winrar');
      }
    })
})
```

**Controller**

```
function publish() {

  $form = $this->input->get('jsonForm');

  echo json_decode($form);

  $data = array(

  'movieid' => $this->input->post('id')

  );

  $this->load->model('publish_model');
  $this->publish_model->add_record($data);
  $this->load->model('NewsFeed_model');
  $feed['queryMovies'] = $this->NewsFeed_model->getPublications();        
  $this->load->view('news_feed_view', $feed);     

}
```

Comment: Didn't you meant to do: `url: '/publishlinks/publish',` with a relative path? Also you can add a failure callback to the ajax function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget semicolons. They can be important. And, `dataType` in the `ajax` request refers to the data coming back from the request not the data being sent by the request.

Start with modifying your ajax:

```
$('form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var title = $('#title:input').val();

    alert(title);

    var urlsStr = $("#links").val();
    var urls = urlsStr.match(/\bhttps?:\/\/[^\s]+/gi);
    var formData = {
       title: title,
        urls: urls
    };                

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    cache: false,
    data: formData,
    url: 'publishlinks/publish',
    success:
      function(response) {
        alert('winrar');
      }
   });
});
```

Your data will be attached as query string which your controller can then pick up. From the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> The data option can contain either a query string of the form key1=value1&key2=value2, or a map of the form {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}. If the latter form is used, the data is converted into a query string using jQuery.param() before it is sent.

Modify your controller to pick up the query string vars.

Here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jensbits/2F4kN/

Comment: @amiawizard json isn't doesn't seem to be a factor. You were decoding json in the controller because you thought that is what you were getting back (I think - not sure why were decoding json there). Now your controller can just grab the query string vars `$_GET` I believe in php and go from there. `publish()` in your controller appears to create feed on some kind but doesn't appear to use the data returned from the ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you meant to do: `url: '/publishlinks/publish',` with a relative path? Also you can add a failure callback to the ajax function: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Also you should really add a `return false;` add the end of the `$('form').submit(function() {` function to prevent the form from being submitted the 'normal' way.

Or use:

```
$('form').submit(function(e)

e.preventDefault();
e.stopPropagtion();
```

Comment: without e.stopPropagtion(); it sends data but doesn't load my news feed view.